# updating a panel has no effect

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to update a panel but it doesn't have an effect. The update column and update text on the other hand work fine. Is `panel.update` broken?

In my application the tab contains several plots. One of the plots needs to be periodically replaced by a new plot (I can not simply update the column data).

- `bokeh==2.2.1`

*minimal working example*:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Tabs, Paragraph, Panel
from bokeh.layouts import column


COUNTER = 0
PAR = Paragraph(text='initial paragraph')
COLUMN = column(children=[PAR])
PANEL = Panel(child=COLUMN, title='response time')


def update_column():
    global COUNTER, COLUMN
    
    par = Paragraph(text=f'counter = {COUNTER}')
    COLUMN.update(children=[par])
    COUNTER += 1
    
    print("update column done")
    

def update_panel():
    global COUNTER, PANEL
    
    par = Paragraph(text=f'counter = {COUNTER}')
    PANEL.update(child=column(children=[par]))
    COUNTER += 1
    
    print("update panel done")
    

def update_text():
    global COUNTER, PAR

    PAR.update(text=f'counter = {COUNTER}')
    COUNTER += 1
    
    print("update text done")


doc = curdoc()
panels = []
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[PANEL])

doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update_panel, period_milliseconds=1000)
doc.add_root(tabs)
```

- `callback=update_column` works
- `callback=update_text` works
- `callback=update_panel` does not work

Answer (score 1):

Updates to the `Panel` properties are not wired at all. Please create an issue on GitHub if you need that functionality.

As a workaround, you can wrap the `child` of a panel in a column and then update the `children` property of that column:

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Tabs, Panel, Div, Button

p = Panel(title='Panel', child=column(Div(text='Panel content')))
ts = Tabs(tabs=[p])

b = Button(label='Update panel content')


def update_panel():
    p.child.children = [Div(text='Updated panel content')]


b.on_click(update_panel)

curdoc().add_root(column(ts, b))
```

Comment: "need" is relative. I can easily work around it, was just wondering if I am missing something since a Panel has the update method.